# WebGL Quaternion Camera

Tags: camera, webgl, quaternions

I haven't yet developed a good intuition for quaternions, so that could be part of my problem, but they are mostly easy to visualize so I based my WebGL camera on them.  The problem is, I need to support both walking the model/environment and orbiting a point.

The code for walking works fine, and so does orbiting.  However, when switching between them, that's the problem.

HERE IS A FIDDLE that shows the problem: [**PROBLEM DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/V3Pku/3/)

When switching between walking and orbiting, the camera pops locations.  Here is my update function:

```
if(isOrbit) {
    var eye = vec3.create();

    vec3.sub(eye, this.eye, this.orbit);

    mat4.fromRotationTranslation(this.orbitMatrix, this.orbitRotation, this.orbit);
    mat4.fromRotationTranslation(this.eyeMatrix,   this.eyeRotation,   eye);        
    mat4.multiply(this.mvMatrix, this.orbitMatrix, this.eyeMatrix);
}
else {                
    mat4.fromRotationTranslation(this.mvMatrix, this.eyeRotation, this.eye);    
}
```

The problem is that it seems in the first section, the eye value is relative to the camera, whereas in the second, it's not (obviously).  However, I've tried a few different things to correct for the eye location when orbiting, and that helps but the rotation is not accounted for in both cases.  I've tried various things to account for eye rotation when moving to orbit, and for orbit rotation when moving to walk, but it keeps not working :^(

Any pointers on what I should be doing/trying here?  Doing either operation (walk/orbit) by itself seems straightforward, but switching seems to be my problem.

Comment: I don't think you need two different cases. I played around with your fiddle and if you just use the part that happens when isOrbit is true for all cases then it seems to work fine with no jumping.

Comment: yeah, I could do that, but if you watch closely, the walk movement is different if you do that.  For instance, use just the isOrbit section, and then look down, and try to walk forward.  Instead of moving forward along the "ground", the camera moves straight towards the ground (along forward vector of camera).  Which is not the desired behavior.  So that's why there are two different ways.  Maybe I that's my problem...

Comment: What is 'orbit' supposed to do exactly?  It looks like it's doing the reverse of what I normally think of.   When I think of orbit, I think that moving the mouse will move the camera and keep looking at one point.  What your camera seems to be doing is rotating around a point and the direction it is looking is rotating as well instead of fixating on a point.

Comment: Specifically I'm thinking that from your explanation it seems like you want to do something like switch from a 3rd or 1st person perspective to a camera that orbits around a point of interest.  To do that with no 'popping' would require tweening from the orbit back to the 'eye' which doesn't seem to be in your sample.  What do you think it should look like when you transition from an 'orbit' looking at something from the side back to the eye?

Answer (score 0):

Multiply whole mvMatrix by `mat4.multiply(this.mvMatrix, this.orbitMatrix, this.eyeMatrix);` after translating part, because `fromRotationTranslation` assigns completely new values to your matrix, while orbiting part takes your translated matrix and MULTIPLIES it by the computed rotation. Also I would suggest you to just modify only the position part of the mvMatrix instead of modifying whole, so rotation elements would stay the same. In my case it looks like this:

```
   var moveDirection = this.rotation.getForwardVector();
   this.position.addSelf(moveDirection.multiplyByScalar(-elapsedTime));
   MVMatrix.setTranslation(this.position);
```

where `getForwardVector()` computes a forward vector from the rotation quaternion and `setTranslation()` modifies only 12, 13 and 14th matrices elements. This method will also translate the camera vertically, just along the camera's forward vector.